# ShowDialog takes too much time on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2016

```
var form = new MyForm(someargs);
//400 ms
form.ShowDialog();
...
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //4500 ms since form.ShowDialog() on Windows 2016

}
```

The time elapsed between the launch of `form.ShowDialog()` and the moment when Load event handler `myForm_Load` raised :

1. on Windows Server 2008R2 ~250ms
2. on Windows Server 2016   ~4500ms

Hardware:

1. Windows Server 2008R2 2.8x12 GHz physical server
2. Windows Server 2016   2.4x20 GHz Hyper-V virtual machine

MyForm's structure is:
  `TableLayoutPanel` with `Dock==DockStyle.Fill`. It has about two ten of `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `Label` etc. Yet two `Button`, one `TabControl` and one `DataGridView`. And two instance of my derived UserControl.

MyForm's `DoubleBuffered` property is set to`true`. I tried `false`, but speed did not speed up.
What take so much time? What can I try yet?

---

#### Update

Event handlers' code has been profiled with my own profiler based on StopWatch. And then I know that the pause contains two part. Every time it appears before `MyUserControl.SelectedValue` setter has called. Perhaps it is important, that `SelectedValue` is bindable property of `MyUserControl` class with `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("SelectedValue")]`

Also, I know if I delete both my UserControl instances MyForm will be show quickly. 
However, I don't know what exactly spend so much time.

---

#### Update 2

I've found the *"perpetrator"*. It is a `ComboBox` with large count of items in the DataSource. Currently, I can present [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new MyForm(); //  76ms 2008R2;  123ms 2016
        form.ShowDialog();       //1820ms 2008R2;12440ms 2016
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{        
    private readonly ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox();
    public MyForm()
    {
        var manyItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 66_000)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Key = t,
                Value1 = t.ToString(),
                Value2 = t.ToString() + t.ToString()
            })
            .ToList();
        myComboBox.DataSource = manyItems;
        myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
        myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value2";
        this.Controls.Add(myComboBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you File > New Project and create a blank WinForm project does it do the same? *Edit -- I just did a test on Server 2016 Hyper-V instance I have and the answer is no, it's quick. I think we're going to need more info to help here.

Comment: @fourwhey You are right. It seems that my question is offtopic...

Comment: does controls of your `MyForm` has event handlers? do you debug them? how much time does them consume?

Comment: You are testing performance in difference environments then the result can not be referred. Perhaps, your virtual machine is weaker than your physical server is the reason.

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, they have event handlers. Good idea, thanks. Though I tested them, and now can say they take little bit of time.

Comment: also check how often does this handlers are called. I mean, even if handler takes only 4ms to run, but if you run it 1000 times this will be more then 4s

Comment: Did you try to use a profiler?

Comment: @DanielW. Yes, I did. Visual Studio Community Profiler says nothing, only that `ShowDialog()` is long, and the method uses System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll. Also, I used my own profiler based on `StopWatch`. I updated the question.

Comment: my guess is that your app startup code is doing something defendant on the environment and its different between yr test machines. My guess are a) dns lookup timing out, b) cert crl check